# Strange rbenv behavior in fish shell

Tags: rbenv, fish

Very simple situation. This is what I did:

```
$ rbenv local 1.9.3-p448
```

Then I opened a new tab in Terminal (on OS X) and while still in the same directory, I do:

```
$ ruby -v
```

and get back `ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]`. Then I do:

```
$ fish
$ ruby -v
```

and get back `ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin13.1.0]`

The `.ruby-version` file is present and contains only the text `1.9.3-p448`. What is going on here?